# collapsable panel not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an issue working with panel collapse where I have a to create dynamic data-target and id's for panel because I have list of items in ng-repeat but the problem is the collapsible panel is not in the scope of the triggering panel
Here is the html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="topics in oJdDetails.topics">
        <a style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+'collapse'+'_' + $index}}" ng-click="fngetQList(topics,$index)">
            <p class="col-xs-3">{{topics}}</p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign col-xs-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="{{'collapse'+'_' + index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <p class="col-xs-6">Question Lists</p>
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-change="fnSearchQList(search)">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Search question " activetooltip aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="fnshowInputQList()">
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="col-xs-8">Add Question List</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign col-xs-4" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller code is as below:

```
$scope.fngetQList = function(topics,index) {
        $scope.index = index;
    };
```

the array of topics is for example:["html","css","angular"]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong but when I click on 1st item the panel is getting opened with "collapse in " class but when I click on second item there still the "collapse in " class is getting appened which results in closing of the panel instead of opening the panel.

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6625/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say ....

Comment: i think you already asked this question

Comment: yes ,
but it isn't solved yet

Comment: you need each link to open it's own panel? so by clicking the 3 links, 3 panels should be opened?

Comment: @Apostolos yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

i dont know if this is correct but it does what you want. i added the popup div inside the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="topics in topics">
         <a style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+'collapse'+'_' + $index}}" ng-click="fngetQList(topics,$index)">
            <p class="col-xs-3">{{topics}}</p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign col-xs-1" aria-hidden="true" />
            <div id="{{'collapse'+'_' + $index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                     <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                           <p class="col-xs-6">Question Lists</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                           <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Click here</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach but i dont think so it should be in ng-repeat

Comment: shouldt there be at least 3 divs? i mean... if you add the index to the div header, you will see that header is changed but the same div collapses/expands because there is only this reference. i dont know if my thoughts are not correct, but that's what i actually see. header is changed correctly, and the same object is collapsed/expanded